# How to hide Dokan Plugin Store Profile Image in Store List as well as in Store Single page?

Tags: dokan

Dokan Multi Vendor Plugin - I wish to hide Profile Image of Vendor using code in funtions.php or css code, in store list and vendor single page. I could not find any settings in the plugign to hide the profile picture of vendor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

On the store list page you can use

```
.seller-avatar{
display:none;}
```

For the main store page you can turn off avatars in WordPress settings which will turn off all avatars or use

```
.profile-info-head{
display:none;}
```

visibility will also work